# Using Radgridview directly for data Manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, radgridview, rad-controls

So i am using RadGridView for Winforms.

Now what i want to do is to perform data manipulation in the radgridview and datasource to get updated after the row loses foucs. I don't want to use textboxes or any other control for entering data.

Something like this

[image: Picture before adding new row]

And after i press the new add new row and enter data

[image]

Now this data isn't being updated in the dataSource to update i need a query that needs to executed against the datasource.

Now i haven't been able to build a query because i haven't been able to figure out how to access the data of the newly created cells so that i can build a query and pass to `SQLCeDataAdapter` for execution.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about RadGridView, but I use DataGridView, wich I guess works the same way

You need to get the datarow so u can update to the database

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)eTipoDocumentoBindingSource.Current).Row;
```

once you have it, you can use the DataTableAdapter method update(row) to save changes to the database

You can do that, either in the click event of a save button, or in the event of focused row  changed